# Is Robolectric able to assert that methods have been invoked?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-2.1-eclair, robolectric

I've got a button defined in my layout as follows :

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/speakButton"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/speak"
                android:onClick="speak"
                />
```

The `onClick` binds to a method in my activity, such as :

```
public void speak(View v)
    {
        // Do my stuff here
    }
```

Using Robolectric, I'm able to create a simple test class for that activity, I'd like to know if its possible that I could have a test that invokes the button, and ensures the method in my activity was invoked OK.

(I've got a whole bunch of buttons throughout my app, so intending to have tests to ensure they are wired up correctly, unless anyone has any suggestions as to why I shoudln't bother)

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MyActivityTest
{
    private MyActivitymActivity;
    private Button speakButton;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        mActivity = new MyActivity();
        mActivity.onCreate(null);

        speakButton = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(com.jameselsey.apps.androidsam.R.id.speakButton);

    }

    @Test
    public void testButtonsVisible()
    {
        assertThat(speakButton.getVisibility(), equalTo(View.VISIBLE));        
    }

    @Test
    public void buttonsInvokeIntendedMethods()
    {
        // Unsure how to implement this test
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used them but I believe you can do this with the `TouchUtils` class. Here is a link to the [Android TouchUtils docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/TouchUtils.html). In particular you should look at the `clickView` method.